# How do I use Redis to store and retrieve data?

Tags: node.js, redis

Is there a way data can be stored in `redis` from one file and retrieved from another file, I mean the way it is with `local storage`, that is to say;

for example;

***1.Redis***(Example of what I want to achieve, not based on correct sytnax)

```
// fileA.js
const redis = require("redis");

const redisHost = "localhost";
const redisPort = process.argv[3] || 3000;

const client = redis.createClient({
  port: redisPort,
  host: redisHost
});

client.set("PIN", "VC-5269");
```

```
// file B.js
...
client.get("PIN", function(err, response) {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  } else {
    console.log(response); -->> expected value: "VC-5269"
  }
});
```

***2.local storage***

```
// file.js
localStorage.setItem("PIN", "VC-5269");
```

```
// fileB.js
localStorage.getItem('PIN'); -->> expected value: "VC-5269"
```

**Basically**, Am having `api` that is sending a PIN to user's phone, then I want to grab that copy of the PIN such that I match it with the one the user will supply, at the moment, I want to work it from the backend in node.js

Comment: I think your question is too much confusing. please explain the specific problem

Comment: @ManjeetThakur, I have edited the question, hopefully it is clearer ?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve this problem

> First ways using the export module

```
// fileA.js
const redis = require("redis");

const redisHost = "localhost";
const redisPort = process.argv[3] || 3000;

const client = redis.createClient({
  port: redisPort,
  host: redisHost
});

client.set("PIN", "VC-5269");

module.exports = client;





// file B.js
const {client} = require("./fileA.js");
...
client.get("PIN", function(err, response) {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  } else {
    console.log(response); -->> expected value: "VC-5269"
  }
});
```

> Using Second Way [Node Event
>   Emitter](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html)

---

> Third ways  using [Redis pubsub](https://redis.io/topics/pubsub)

```
// fileA.js

const redis = require("redis");
const redisHost = "localhost";
const redisPort = process.argv[3] || 3000;

const publisher = redis.createClient({
  port: redisPort,
  host: redisHost
});

 publisher.publish("PIN", "VC-5269")


// B.js

const redis = require("redis");
const redisHost = "localhost";
const redisPort = process.argv[3] || 3000;

const publisher = redis.createClient({
  port: redisPort,
  host: redisHost
});


subscriber.subscribe("PIN");

subscriber.on("message",(channel,message) => {
    // here you get pin
    console.log("Received data :"+message);
})
```